# HtmlUnit click event on submit button doesn't work

Tags: java, htmlunit

this week I starded a homework and reading on this forum I found the "solution" of my problem.
My programm parses a HTML page of a website and get some data. Well this is not difficult. My problem is how to get data on the website. 
Using HtmlUnit I know that's possible, and reading their tutorials and some code on the web I wrote my simple test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void myClient() throws Exception {

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.atb.bergamo.it/ITA/Default.aspx?SEZ=2&PAG=38&MOD=LINTRV");

    final HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("form1");

    final HtmlSubmitInput filtra = form.getInputByName("ctl13$btnFilter");

    page = filtra.click();

    final String pageAsXml = page.asXml();

    System.out.println(pageAsXml);

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
  }
}
```

This code gets the remote page, clicks a submit button in a form of the page and after that prints the submit result on the console.

The problem is when I use the click event, because nothing changes in the web page. 
Infact it must appear a new table with some data which I want to collect, but it doesn't.

Can you tell me where I get wrong, please?

Do you know another way to do what I'd like to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if this code throws an exception loading the initial page (specifically executing the JavaScript).
From my experience this isn't uncommon and can be attributed to HtmlUnit's JavaScript engine(Rhino).

I would suggest trying Selenium WebDriver instead.

This code should get the source of the page:

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.atb.bergamo.it/ITA/Default.aspx?SEZ=2&PAG=38&MOD=LINTRV");
        WebElement filtra = driver.findElement(By.name("ctl13$btnFilter"));
        filtra.click();
        //make sure to wait till the results div is loaded
        //waits 10 seconds or then throws an exception
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                List<WebElement> divTags = d.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
                for(WebElement tag: divTags){
                    if(tag.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("ctl13_divRisultati")){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
        System.out.println(pageSource);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```